# How does one ride a broom in Harry Potter films?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-transportation, flying-brooms

I was wondering, after watching the Harry Potter films several times earlier, the way the witches and wizards fly on brooms is quite impossible the way I see it.

- Sitting on such a thin broom is awfully uncomfortable and difficult, there’s no way one can prevent spinning and sliding off. How do they hold on it and on to it?
- The leg holders (or whatever they are called) are too far behind, and keeping your legs in such a position for too long will result in pain and more, at least the way shown in the films.
- When upside down or in a vertical position, there is no way a person could hold on to the broom without severe force, and the grip should be extra strong. Does magic help stay on the broom?

Comment: Are you asking if a *real* magical broom can be flown like the ones you see in the film?

Comment: @Valorum More of a "why don't they fall, does it hurt to sit on a broomstick, and what prevents them from being uncomfortable"?

Comment: Because of magic...

Comment: Are you looking for a *broom saddle* or something? Your question title and the body don't seem to match.

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: W.r.t. point three - it has to do with, well, the buttocks - I'm not going to go into any details, don't worry - which is why Moody was so exercised about Harry keeping his wand in his pants pocket - he was worried Harry might not be able to fly brooms in the future and he knew how important that was to him ...

Comment: Magic, of course! I don't know exactly how brooms work in the Harry Potter universe, mostly because I am a major fan of Star Wars, but just a regular fan of Harry Potter, but I assume that they magically stay stable and do not spin around a lot. I don't really know.

Comment: I thought my answer nicely dealt with the issue in an in-universe way. Is there anything else you'd want to see before considering an acceptance?

Comment: @Valorum Sorry Valorum, your answer is great.

Comment: Just checking...your suspension of disbelief cruises right by the flying brooms, but piles up at how to balance on them?  :-)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The very short answer is that while older designs of broomstick were extremely uncomfortable, modern brooms are fitted with a "[cushioning charm](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Cushioning_Charm)" intended to make the ride smoother and more pleasant. Pedal placement is therefore down to the individual's personal choice rather than the raw necessity of staying on the broomstick

[image]
<sub><sup>[image courtesy of 'Quidditch Through the Ages'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quidditch_Through_the_Ages)</sup></sub>

Comment: who knew this question had an answer? +1!

Comment: How come it didn't work when the twins got boils in places they weren't willing to discuss but which were apparently impacted by their broom?  And they were so good at charms too ...

Comment: I would assume that the cushioning charms make it as comfortable to sit on a broom as in a chair, or racing saddle. I think you’d find that sitting on those things would be rather uncomfortable with aforementioned boils.

Comment: It's also possible that the charms wear off after awhile and need to be recast.

Comment: @AaronGullison the wikia link mentions that the charm is part of the manufacturing process, so I doubt it'd need recasting.

Comment: @JAD Or at the very least not more recasting than any of the other charms placed on the broom.

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach, Valorum knew! As always! :)

Comment: @davidbak Good question. Why not make it one?

Comment: Could you reference the primary sources for that wiki-article too, in case the wiki goes down?

Comment: @eirikdaude - I'll happily replace it if the link goes dead but the HP wiki is a very stable source, plus the cushioning charm is mentioned in a bunch of different places and books so having a link to the wiki makes more sense than having multiple separate (and unnecessary) links.

Comment: @Valorum - By "mentioned in a bunch of different places" I assume you mean just *Quidditch thorough the Ages*.

Comment: @ibid - In relation to brooms, you're correct but the charm itself appears in multiple places (QTTA, HPDH and CC)

Answer (score 13):

I've been to the Harry Potter recording studios in London, where they had a couple of brooms that you could sit on and make a green screen recording.

The brooms have small seats, which you sit on, as described by @Valorum above.

[image: Harry Potter Studios green screen broom]

As you can see there is also an engine attached to the broom, which makes small movements to add effects.

So in this case a seat and some foot pedals give you enough stability.

I think that magic has some effect on the entirety of flying a broom. Especially the part about being upside down.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! This is an nice answer but to the wrong question. You seem to be answering how the actors would have used the brooms out of universe rather than how the characters use the brooms in universe.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Thank you! I acknowledge my mistake. I now understand the entirety of the question.

Comment: Reading the title, I assumed this was the question being asked as well